# Trying to save in quick.db channel after interaction but cannot save channel and prevent making channnel

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots, quick.db

I am using 'discord.js' v13 library with 'quick.db' npm package.

I am trying to save the channel from the interaction, but when I do it for first time bot sends me that I have already the channel. When I try for a second and third time, it sends me the same message and recreates a channel.

The JavaScript code I am using:

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', async(interaction) => {
  if (interaction.customId === "general") {
    await interaction.deferUpdate();

    const channel = await interaction.guild.channels.create(`name-${interaction.member.user.username}`, {
      type: 'GUILD_TEXT'
    }).then(async channel => {
        const del = new MessageButton()
          .setStyle("DANGER")
          .setLabel(" Delete")
          .setCustomId("del");
        const delbut = new MessageActionRow()
          .addComponents([
            [del]
          ])
        await channel.send({
          content: `test`,
          embeds: [test],
          components: [delbut]
        }).catch(e => {
          console.log(e.message)
        });
        const channelID = await interaction.guild.channels.cache.get(channel.id);
        const newchannel = await db.set(`channel_${interaction.guild.id}_${interaction.channel.id}`, interaction.member.id)

        if (newchannel) {
          const savedChannel = await db.get(`channel_${interaction.guild.id}_${interaction.channel.id}`)

          interaction.member.send({
            content: `Channel: ${channelID}`
          })
        }
      }
    })

  if (interaction.customId === "del") {
    await interaction.deferUpdate();
    interaction.message.channel.delete()
  }

}
});
```